# .htaccess rewriterule not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have created a `.htaccess` rewiterule, but it is not doing anything.

The rule is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /showproduct.php?get-uid=$1&prod=$2 [L]
```

What I want to happen is that the following URL:

`http://naturesgifts.co.nz/showproduct.php?get-uid=8&prod=whitesagespray`

Changes to:

`http://naturesgifts.co.nz/8/whitesagespray.html`

However no redirect happens.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} get-uid=([^&]+)&prod=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^showproduct.php$ /%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
```

Line 1: check if the query string contains the param `get-uid` and the param `prod`, `[^&]` matches any characters except `&` character

Line 2: if the request uri matches to `showproduct.php` exactly, redirect to `/%1/%2.html` permanently. `%1` is the backreference to the first capture group `([^&])` whereas `%2` matches the second capture group. `[R=301]` flag makes it redirect permanently.